# SQL syntax error, Can't find it?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''comments' ( 'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'article_i' at line 1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'comments' (
    'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'article_id' int(10) NOT NULL,
    'comment' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    'time' datetime NOT NULL,
    'name' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    'email' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    KEY 'fk_comments_article'('article_id')
);
```

Does anyone see the syntax error?

Comment: `'id'` is a character literal (a "string") not a column name (identifier). Remove all those single quotes and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    article_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    comment varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    time datetime NOT NULL,
    name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY 'fk_comments_article'(article_id)
);
```

or try with back ticks:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `article_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY fk_comments_article(`article_id`)
);
```

You are getting this error because when you write `'id'` then it is treated as a string not a column which you intend

Comment: @user3481441:- You are welome!

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks instead of single qoutes .Single qoutes are used for string literals.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `article_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY fk_comments_article(`article_id`)
);
```

backticks **`**  are used to enable identifires be used a column name / table name if they happen to be Keywords in MySQL .

It is the recommended way as it is highly unlikely that we know all the keywords beforehand and may end up using one of keyword as our name for column/table like you have done for column **`time`** in your `CREATE` satement .

But you should avoid using keywords known to you as identifires.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Single quotes, tested below query in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    article_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    comment varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    time datetime NOT NULL,
    name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY fk_comments_article(article_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove '

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
    id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    article_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    comment varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    time datetime NOT NULL,
    name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY fk_comments_article(article_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of the single quotes `'` with back ticks or simply remove the single quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `article_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `time` datetime NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fk_comments_article`(`article_id`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used single quotes which is worng and used for string only not for enclosing column names. Removethat and use backticks since you have some keywords like `TIME, NAME`:

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `article_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `comment` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY fk_comments_article(`article_id`)
);
```